# Javascript function to redirect multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

Redirect multiple pages using javascript.

I'm trying to redirect multiple pages using the javascript below.

When a user goes to a webpage with the **old-url** I want the user to automatically be redirected to the **new-url**. I've tried the script below but doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function redirectOldUrls() {
  const urlMappings = {
    '/old-url-1': '/new-url-1',
    '/old-url-2': '/new-url-2',
    '/old-url-3': '/new-url-3'
  };

  const currentUrlPath = window.location.pathname;

  // Check if current URL matches one of the old URLs
  if (currentUrlPath in urlMappings) {
    const newUrl = urlMappings[currentUrlPath];
    window.location.href = newUrl; // Open the new URL in the current tab
  }
}

redirectOldUrls(); // Call the function to run it
```

Comment: Does anything happen? Is there an error in the developer console? I'm assuming this script is running on the old-url page?

Comment: Nothing happens. It just stays on the old page.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `window.location.pathname` is actually matching *exactly* any of the values you have in your 'urlMappings' array? e.g. does the actual path have a trailing slash, etc?